# clear:both not working when trying to place a div below floated divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a `.left` div that floated left and `.right` div that's floated right and they are w/n the `.navBarWrapper` div. I applied `clear:both` to `.searchBar`, but `searchBar` is still showing up on the top left corner of the page as shown by the blue rectangle below. How to fix this?

[image]

```css
.navBarWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.float_left {
  float: left;
}

.float_right {
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 8.02%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.searchBar {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBarWrapper">
  <div class="top bar">
    <ul class="left float_left">
      <li class="title">Photo Albums</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right float_right">
      <li class="buttons">
        <a class="iconLink" href=""><img class="iconNotHover" src="images/uploadImage.png" alt="uploadImage" width="40" align="middle" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Select</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class = "iconTitle">New Album </span><img class = "icons" src = "images/addAlbum.png" alt = "addAlbum" width="30" align = "right"/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="searchBar">
  <img src="images/search.png" alt="search" width="40">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to remove `position: fixed;` from `.navBarWrapper`

`.searchBar` is relative to the body as `.navBarWrapper` has it's position fixed. If you put both classes as position relative it should work, to do this just ommit position on `.navBarWrapper`. You also don't need to put `clear: both` on `.searchBar`. It would have sense to have the clear both only if `.searchBar` div were also inside the `navBarWrapper` div.

Your final code should be

```
.navBarWrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.float_left {
    float: left;
}

.float_right {
    float: right;

}

.bar {
    height: 8.02%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.searchBar {

}
```

Comment: I want to the navBarWrapper to be `fixed` because the nav bars are suppose to stay on the top of the page as you scroll. Is there a way to do that without removing `fixed`?

Comment: sure, just add a margin-top: size of .navBarWrapper to the `.searchBar` class. In this case the .navBarWrapper should have a fixed height which will match the margin-top specified on .searchBar. eg: `.navBarWrapper { z-index: 1; width: 100%; height: 100px or 10%;} .searchBar {
margin-top: 100px or 10%;
}`

Comment: when I specify `margin-top` for the search bar it also pushes down the nav bars

Comment: try to replace it with padding-top instead of margin-top

Comment: padding-top doesn't move the floating divs, but it doesn't move the search bar down, it just makes the search bar into a bigger rectangle.

Comment: The original answer i proposed you works, you should have not done it as i said. Look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/872ztcut/